# Android Lint from command line and from Android Studio don't match

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, static-analysis

I have a module that **I know** includes some unused color resources. When I run lint from Android Studio, it includes the output that I expect. When I run it from the command line, however, it does not find these unused resources.

How can I get the command line to report these unused resources (preferably as a warning)?

---

### Running lint from Android Studio

Run inspection by name:

[image]

Output:

[image]

### Running lint from the command line (using gradle)

My build.gradle configuration:

```
lintOptions {
    check 'UnusedResources'
}
```

Actually running the task:

```
$ ./gradlew :lib:lint

> Task :lib:lint
Ran lint on variant release: 0 issues found
Ran lint on variant debug: 0 issues found

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
```

I know that the gradle configuration is "working", because if I remove the `check 'UnusedResources'` line it will find other issues (`check` makes it run just a single inspection). Also notable that specifying `check 'ThisIsObviouslyNonsense'` gives the same output (a "successful" run that finds zero issues).

---

### Reproducing the problem

I can't provide real source code, but reproducing the issue in a new project is very simple.

1. Use the Android Studio wizard to create a new project. (I chose "Empty Activity", Kotlin, and a min API of 19.)
2. Add this to your colors.xml: `<color name="unused">#f00</color>`
3. Open `app/build.gradle` and do the following:

   1. Change `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` to `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`
   2. Delete the `applicationId` line from `defaultConfig`
   3. Add this `lintOptions` block to the `android` block:

```
lintOptions {
    check 'UnusedResources'
}
```

Now go to the command line and run `./gradlew lint`. You will see 0 issues.

It is notable that everything seems to work before converting the module to a library (running lint detects the unused color resource just fine). This *might* have something to do with the fact that library resources are considered "public"... but in my real library we've explicitly declared that resources are private by default.

Comment: Is there a lint.xml configuration file?

Comment: No, just gradle configuration

Comment: When you run it with AndroidStudio, do you specify the library? or is it through the whole project? And, about the results given by AndroidStudio, are the warnings in the "lib" project? What about the result of launching "./gradlew lint"? what's the result?

Comment: Here is a [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/lint-dev/TpTMBMlwPPs) to something that may be related. Take a look at the 4/19/18 response.

Comment: Could you give us a sample project?

Comment: @FrancisBacon I added reproduction steps to the question. Using Android Studio to create your own project is a lot simpler than providing a whole repo.

Comment: @BenP. Thanks, Ben, I managed to reproduce it, will dig it out later.